# Determining how long it takes an object to reach a certain speed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity, calculus

Robotics related. On a linear servo driven rail one can typically set acceleration and maximum move speed. I am trying to determine the amount of seconds it takes the load to accelerate to a certain specified speed. An example would be:

Initial speed: 0
Acceleration/deceleration speed: 50mm/sec2
Ultimate velocity: 75 mm/sec
Move distance: 2000mm

This will start at zero, speed up to it's move speed, travel a distance and then decelerate to zero.

```
     -------
    /       \
   /         \
  /           \
 /             \
/               \
```

How would one determine the time from str=art to max speed?
How would one determine the total time of the movement?

Answer (score 0):

Simply divide the motion into three phases.

During constant acceleration and deceleration the equation of motion is

v = u + at     You have u=0 in acceleration and v= 0 in deceleration.

If you want the distance travelled during acceleration

s = ut + 0.5 at^2

For the constant speed phase:

s = ut

You have the distance and speed.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way is to draw speed-time graph like you have already. It wil be a trapezium. Maximum speed and time axis give you dimensions of trapezium. The area gives you distance travelled. Slope of lines gives acceleration. All you need to do is a bit of mathematics